# Check User Permissions C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, permissions

Is it possible that after the user logs in, the application checks what permissions the user have.  Currently I have a User table which also have a foreign key named Access ID. So I want the application to check the Access ID of the logged in user and see whether its a 1 or 2. If its a 1 the user can only view content and if its a 2 then the user can also Edit and Delete. I'm new to C# and SQL Server connections and would appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and a very common scenario in many applications. There are many solutions to this problem, and often there is a built in solution to handle it. Some more information about your application would be helpful. Is this a web application, WPF, console application? How are your users authenticating to the application?

Comment: @SeanOB Hi, my application is a Windows application built with C#. Thanks

Comment: That's very common, but requires work on both the front end and back end. It sounds like the back end is already set up, The front end developer will need to write the logic to handle what you are asking. You could theoretically write stored procedures which accept the "Access ID" as a parameter and perform the update if it's a 2 and reject if it's a 1, but ideally you would perform such a check in the front end application itself (displaying "Edit" buttons depending on the "Access ID" variable). FYI, your question is very broad in scope.